# How to transfer multiple repositories from one team to another in bitbucket in a single bulk operation

Tags: bitbucket

I need to transfer multiple `bitbucket` repositories from one Group to Another is this possible ?

I have read this but does not mention anything about multiple repository transfer
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Change+or+transfer+repository+ownership

Comment: why not simply clone/fork it (by the other team) ?

Comment: @alfasin that could be an option but how do you clone all the repos in a single bulk operation ?

Comment: Write a short python/bash script that does it. Shouldn't be difficult. See: https://confluence.atlassian.com/plugins/servlet/remotepageview?pageId=222724129#UsetheBitbucketRESTAPIs-URIStructureandMethods